# How to check if user selected file for upload php

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a table made for updating data for admins of my page. They have a choice to update Pruduct name, price and the image. 
If they do not select an image the same image is kept. On the other hand, if the image is selected then the image should be uploaded into a folder. 
Here's my code.

```html
<?php
if (empty($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
     echo "no file mate";
    $uploadImg = $_POST['imgpath'];
}
if ($_FILES['image']['error'] != 0) {
     echo "working";
     $folder = "Images/";
     $uploadImg = $folder . basename ($_FILES['image']['name']);
     if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $uploadImg)) {
         echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["image"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";}
} ?>
```

my form :

```html
<?php while ($row=$query->fetch()) {?>
      <tr><form action ="InsertScripts/update-product.php" method ="POST">
        <td><input type="text" name="product" value="<?php echo $row['ProductName']?>"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="price" value="<?php echo $row['Price']?>"/></td>
        <td><div class ="smallpic"><img src = "InsertScripts/<?php echo $row['Image']?>"></div></td>
    <input type="hidden" name="imgpath" value="<?php echo $row['Image']?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['ProductId']?>"/>
  <td><input type ="file" name="image"/></td>
  <td><button type ="submit">Update</button></td>
      </form></tr>
    <?php }?>
```

For some reason, it only displays "no file mate" even when i select a new image for the pruduct. 
Help anyone?

Comment: `<php` if that is your actual syntax, it's incorrect and missing the `?` for it as in `<?php`. Also, where is the HTML for this? Edit: This comment as per the original post https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50086065/1

Comment: why is this tagged as sql?

Comment: i have <?php in my actual code

Comment: edit that then when you will show us what the form looks like.

Comment: added my form code

Comment: Thank you. Consult the duplicate that the question was closed with. Error reporting would have thrown you something about an undefined index error. We're dealing with files here and requires an enctype.

Comment: thanks mate! was super confused why this wasnt working when i have the same code for the other forms and they work just fine. Appreciate it

Comment: added the enctype but still doesnt seem to work . 
is this: 
if ($_FILES['image']['error'] != 0){} the correct way of checking if the file has been selected for upload?